# How to get details exception from published Web Api

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to get detail exception & Stack trace from deployed Web Api?

Even if I deployed in Debug mode, do I get detail error traces?

I got bellow message from server API

> "message": "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception.
>   Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of
>   this exception for details."

**This happened only in server, same code running perfectly in local machine.**

Comment: for me, this was something as simple as sending json in a POST as {...} when I needed to send as [[...}]

Answer (score 17):

Did you check the *content-type* for the request that you are performing?

Sometimes this error comes because you don't specify this value, e.g. **"application/json"** in the headers of the request.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks. Is there a way to default the content-type so that the request doesn't have to specify the content-type?

Comment: If you are using a tool such as Postman or some other, I think you can change the settings in order to specify whatever content is using your application. However, once you invoke your API, the value remains the same and does not bother again.

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario is to have a central place to log any exceptions that happen when requests are being processed, then I would suggest to take a look at 5.1 version of Web API (released couple of days back), specifically the **Global Error Handling** feature.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error

If you go to the above page,you should notice `ExceptionLoggerContext` which gives you details of the exception.

**About Web API versions 5.0 and before:**
In these versions there was no really a central place for catching exceptions. ExceptionFilterAttributes caught exceptions for only certain areas of Web API.